# C pointer arithmetic with struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I am currently writing a new String struct in C as below and practicing pointer arithmetic.

```
struct String {
    uint32_t check;
    uint32_t capacity;
    uint32_t length;
    char data[1];

} String;
```

and I was a bit confused at this part of the code

```
define STRING(s) ((String*)(s - 3*sizeof(uint32_t)))

void utstrfree(char* self) {

//    if(*(self - sizeof(uint32_t) * 3) == SIGNATURE) WHY DOES THIS NOT >WORK?

    assert((STRING(self)->check) == SIGNATURE);     //check if it's a >utstring

    free(self-sizeof(uint32_t) * 3);    //properly free the malloc and alternative could have been free(STRING(self))

}
```

I understand how my STRING macro works and it works properly but I am not quite sure why my if statement doesn't work. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Off topic: is this magically resizing `struct` trick kosher in modern Standard C?

Comment: @user4581301 Modern C should use a flexible array member -- `char data[];`, not `char data[1];`, otherwise it's legit (manipulating the sized strings via char* to the flexible array member is a little fishy, though -- not very type safe).

Comment: No, @user4581301, nor was it ever kosher under any previous standard, though in fact it usually *works*.  These days, the standard has direct support for this sort of thing via [flexible array members](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18).

Comment: Is self a pointer to the String struct, or is self the char data pointer? I think you may be confusing the two.

Comment: Don't mess about with muddled pointer manipulation. You get a pointer from `malloc` and you pass that exact same pointer to `free`. Don't risk any other tosh. Although trying to create a variable sized `struct` is another issue...

Comment: I looked at some old code using a similar ... whatever this is, and it fits what Weather Vane just said. You free what you malloc. This code is risky.

Comment: Thanks folks. I remember having to do this back in the '90s, and figured that by now it was either grandfathered or formalized with rules to make it safe or at least predictable.

Comment: It would be better to replace `3*sizeof(uint32_t)` with `offsetof(String, data)`.

Comment: well you already assert it. If your assert works and you want change it to if try the same with if.

Comment: @user4581301 It invokes undefined behaviour at least since C99 (likely since C90 already) if the array is accessed beyond its boundaries.

Comment: @PSkocik: An array of fixed length is not the same as a FAM and the compiler is allowed to expect the array not to accessed beyond its boundaries. IOW: accessing a fixed-width array (or a VLA) beyond its boundaries invokes undefined behaviour. For a FAM, the compiler is aware it does not know the boundaries, thus the access is safe here.

Comment: ... provided that access does not overrun the memory actually allocated to the object.

Comment: No this is not safe and you assume things not guaranteed. Not sure what use this has anyway, if you have a function which takes such a `struct`, you can already pass the `struct` explicitly, not this hackish construct. If it is not aware, it cannot rely the `char *` points into such an object. Another aspect comes into mind: maintainability and readability of the code. None is given with that and your code is likely to be messed up - including yourself after some months/years.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sure. I just wrote what the compiler can assume. Of course the programmer has to know the current boundaries. That's what I assume is the `capacity` member for (which should be `size_t` along with `length`, btw.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AslakBerby already observed, the expression in your assertion, which I am assuming *does* work, is not equivalent to the condition expression in your commented-out `if` statement.  In particular, since `self` is a `char *`, the expression `*(self - sizeof(uint32_t) * 3)` has type `char`, whereas the expression `STRING(self)->check` has type `uint32_t`.  Supposing that evaluating the latter has defined behavior at all, the former yields only the first byte of the latter, in system-specific storage order.

Overall, though, to the extent that this general scheme works at all, it is brittle and unsafe:

- It makes assumptions about the representation of type `struct String` that implementations are not required to satisfy;
- It routinely overruns array bounds, thus invoking undefined behavior;
- It affords no mechanism for representing in-place substrings;
- It provides enough interoperation with the standard library's string functions to give users an expectation for greater interoperability than it actually provides.

Recommendations:

- Rely on `offsetof()` for computations of relative location within a struct.  It's both safer and clearer.
- Don't even try for direct interoperability with plain `char` array strings -- handle these objects as what they actually are.  After all, the  point of such an exercise is usually not so much the data structure itself, but rather the improved functions that go with it, such as an O(1) version of `strlen()`.  There's no need to go out of your way to accommodate these objects' use with the standard library's functions.
- Consider using a pointer to the data instead of embedding the data directly in the object.  This would certainly do a better job of accommodating resizing, and it could support in-place substrings too.
- If you do embed the data directly in the object, then use a flexible array member to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your if is not equal to the macro. If you should type it out it shall be something like this:

```
if(((String*)(self - 3*sizeof(uint32_t)))->check) == SIGNATURE) ...
```

You need to typecast the pointer you create, then use the attribute you are looking for.

Comment: In particular, given that `self` is a `char *`, the `if` statement compares *a `char`* to `SIGNATURE`.  That appear to not be what he intends.

Comment: Yes. And as we don't know how `SIGNATURE` is defined it impossible to say why not. He could however do this: `if(*((unit32_t*)(self - 3*sizeof(uint32_t))) == SIGNATURE)` Should also work.